# How to automatically move the text to next in mobile responsive html?

Tags: html, css

I have a  tag with line:

```
<h2 class="h2hdng" style="color:#000;font-size:40px;">Set up your <br/>Pacifyr payment account</h2>
```

In mobile responsive view i have written :

```
@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width:430px) {.h2hdng{
        font-size:13px;
        margin-left:75px;
        padding-bottom:0px;
        margin-bottom:4px;
        margin-top: -25px !important;


    }
```

For All views its works fine if i switch to galaxy s5 view its working by the same if i choose ipone5 view its not working,

[image: working fine in galaxy s5 view]

[image: Not working in iphone 5 view]

Answer (score 0):

remove inline style font size `style="color:#000;font-size:40px;"`, write it in embedded or external CSS. it'll work fine.

just adjust font size there. your current media query font size is 13px. you need to increase it. otherwise, it'll not look good.

Comment: Font size is not accepted, so that doesnot cause problem, pacifyr ,payment , acccount each should in line by line

Comment: Galaxy S5's width and iPhone-5's width are not the same. Galaxy S5 is wider than iPhone-5.
you've to decrease your font size for iPhone-5.

Comment: if you don't want to remove inline css, then use !important. your code can be.


`@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width:320px) {
  .h2hdng{
    font-size:25px !important;
  }
}`